# CryptoAPI: CERT_STORE_PROV_MEMORY and thread safety

Tags: winapi, cryptography, x509certificate, cryptoapi

I'm writing a client/server solution using CryptoAPI to provide SSL encryption over a TCP socket. In the client I have a global CERT_STORE_PROV_MEMORY certificate store that I share between all connections (i.e. multiple threads).

My question is whether this is thread safe? Can multiple threads call functions (e.g. CertGetIssuerCertificateFromStore()) on the certificate store at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CertGetIssuerCertificateFromStore()` is a *reading* function. So, concurrent usage of them is safe. Taken `CERT_CONTEXT` will be a copy of existing one, so it can be modified as you wish.